# Add variable to Java OPCUA server

Tags: java, server, opc-ua

I would like to use a java OPC UA server with the prosys OPCUA SDK.
I'm able to start a server with the SimpleServer program but I don't understand how to host variable in this server as boolean, integer...

Here the code I'm using from the package, it start a server but it is empty.

````
public class SimpleServer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    UaServer server = new UaServer();

    if (System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.6")) {
      server.setEnableIPv6(false);
    }

    server.setPort(Protocol.OpcTcp, 52530);
    server.setServerName("OPCUA/SimpleServer");
    server.setBindAddresses(EndpointUtil.getInetAddresses(server.isEnableIPv6()));

    server.getSecurityModes().add(SecurityMode.NONE);
    server.getSecurityModes().addAll(SecurityMode.combinations(
        EnumSet.of(MessageSecurityMode.Sign, MessageSecurityMode.SignAndEncrypt), SecurityPolicy.ALL_SECURE_104));

    server.addUserTokenPolicy(UserTokenPolicies.ANONYMOUS);
    server.setCertificateValidator(new DefaultCertificateValidator(new PkiDirectoryCertificateStore()));

    initializeApplicationIdentity(server);

    // Starts the server
    server.start();

    // Prints connection address that clients can use.
    System.out.println("Server started, connection address:");
    System.out.println(server.getEndpoints()[0].getEndpointUrl());

    //I think the variable should be add here

    // Wait for shutdown
    System.out.println("Enter 'x' to shutdown");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.nextLine(); // blocks until input given
    System.out.println("Shutting down..");
    server.shutdown(2, new LocalizedText("Shutdown by user"));
    System.out.println("Server stopped.");
  }

  /**
   * Define a minimal ApplicationIdentity.
   */
  private static void initializeApplicationIdentity(UaServer server)
      throws SecureIdentityException, IOException, UnknownHostException {
    ApplicationDescription appDescription = new ApplicationDescription();
    appDescription.setApplicationName(new LocalizedText("SimpleServer", Locale.ENGLISH));

    appDescription.setApplicationUri("urn:localhost:UA:SimpleServer");
    appDescription.setProductUri("urn:prosysopc.com:UA:SimpleServer");
    appDescription.setApplicationType(ApplicationType.Server);

    File privateKeyPath = new File("PKI/CA/private");
    String organization = "Sample Organization";
    String privateKeyPassword = "opcua";
    ApplicationIdentity identity = ApplicationIdentity.loadOrCreateCertificate(appDescription, organization,
        privateKeyPassword, privateKeyPath, true);
    server.setApplicationIdentity(identity);
  }

} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at the SampleConsoleServer project which is a more complete server. And read the Tutorial that explains the details.